# Audio Upload with Expressjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, audio, cloudinary

I am working on a music app,how can i upload audio file in my expressjs using cloudinary or any other way?

I tried using thesame format for image upload but didnt work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNdsH.png)

Answer (score 0):

To upload audio using Express JS, you will need to use the multer middleware. Here is an example of how you can set up the multer middleware and use it to handle audio file uploads:

1. First, install the multer package:

> npm install multer

2. Next, require the multer package in your Express app:

> const multer = require('multer')

3. Set up the multer middleware by specifying where you want the uploaded audio files to be stored. For example:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/audio/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})
```

4. Use the multer middleware in your route handling function to handle the audio file upload. For example:

```
app.post('/upload-audio', multer({ storage }).single('audio'), (req, res) => {
  // req.file contains the uploaded audio file
  // Do something with the audio file, such as save it to a database or storage service
  res.send('Audio file successfully uploaded!')
})
```

5. In your HTML form for uploading audio, make sure to include the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute and specify the name of the file input as audio. For example:

```
<form action="/upload-audio" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="audio" accept="audio/*">
  <button type="submit">Upload Audio</button>
</form>
```

*I hope this helps!*

Comment: Yes Jack to an extend it does..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jack's answer, there is a Cloudinary storage engine for Multer you can use to send your files to Cloudinary rather than keeping the assets on disk.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary

When initializing the `CloudinaryStorage` object you can pass parameters to Cloudinary, including the `resource_type`. If you set that to `auto` (default is `image` if none is provided) then Cloudinary assigns the appropriate `resource_type` once it processes the upload request. For audio files, it will assign `resource_type: "video"` because audio files fall under this and for images, it'll assign "image". If you were to upload text files and you used resource_type: "auto" in your request, then Cloudinary will assign "raw" as the resource_type.

You will just need to store (e.g. in your database) the `resource_type`, `type` and `public_id` fields returned in the response to a successful upload and you can then refer to any of your files on Cloudinary.

The reason you want to save the 'resource_type' and 'type' and not only the 'public_id' is because, in Cloudinary, an asset is only unique if in combination with the 'resource_type' and 'type'. E.g. the below assets with the same public_id (`sample`) are different entities because of a different 'resource_type' and/or 'type':

```
image/upload/sample
image/private/sample
video/upload/sample
video/authenticated/sample
```

References:

- https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#asset_types

Comment: Hello Aleksander. Thank you for this link. it was really helpful. But it only covers image uplaod. I am working with the audio and image upload. Is that in the format I will specify both the audio and image format to use

Comment: Hi @Prince11, I updated the answer with more details since they cannot fit inside a comment.